# Еще раз об имени Людмила

Tags: имена-собственные

Почитал тут обсуждение имен из "Руслана и Людмилы", и в одном ответе прозвучало, что имя Людмила — псевдославянское. А почему так? Ведь это вполне православное имя, причем, насколько я знаю, не только русское: в Болгарии есть мужской вариант этого имени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это я писал. Там и пояснение было. Людмила, Светлана, Милослава, Снежана и проч. появились не раньше самого конца XVII века.

Славяне до крещения почти не использовали женских имен (Едва ли не единственное известное - княгиня Ольга, варяжского происхождения). Позденее на Руси появились кальки с греческого (Вера, Надежда, Любовь), но основным обращением к женщине по-прежнему было отчество (вспомните хотя бы Ярославну). Ещё одним подтверждением этого является полное отсутcтвие женских нецерковных имен. 
И только с ростом славянофильских настроений в обществе XVIII века (Сумароков-Державин-Жуковский) женские "славянские" имена прочно вошли в обиход и окончательно были закреплены произведениями Жуковского.

Болгарское имя Людмил не связано с русским женским именем.

Касательно православности имени. Да, сейчас оно вошло в святцы. Но греческого аналога у него нет, так что говорить об исходной каноничности имени не приходится. Но самое-то главное в этой связи то, что исконные славянские имена никак не исходно православные. Их канонизировали уже в христианский период Руси. 
Елинственная Людмила в святцах - Людмила Чешская, жившая в X веке. Не знаю времени её канонизации, но подозреваю, что она была вторичной, после распространения этого имени.

Добавлено ========== 10.07.2012
Я нашел инфу. Святая мученица благоверная княгиня Людмила Чешская была канонизирована в 1100 г. Это несколько меняет мой взляд на всю историю имени, но не трогает обсуждаемого в данной теме. На Руси это имя в то время не существовало, по происхождению она была сербкой, исторической преемствености между современным именем и "превоисnочником" нет.